Compute the character of an irreducible representation of $S_{20}$
Here is the problem:

Assume $(V,\rho)$ is an irreducible representation of $S_{20}$ with $\dim V=2*3^8*13*17*19$.
Let $g$ be a  transposition of $S_{20}$. Calcuate $\vert \mathrm{tr}\rho(g) \vert $.

Here are my attempts:

It follows the context of the book "Representation Theory A First
Course". It is written by William Fulton  and Joe Harris.
By the hook length formula, we have $2\cdot 3^8\cdot 13\cdot 17 \cdot
> 19=\dfrac{20!}{\prod (\mathrm{Hook ~~lengths})}(*)$
In order to slove this problem, I write a C program. It can dispaly
all partitions of  $20$ and compute the right hand of $(*)$ of every
partition.
By the representations of symmetric groups, every irreducible
representations corresponds to a Young diagram.
By the C program, I get $V \cong V_{\lambda}$ where
$\lambda=(8,6,4,2)$ or $\lambda=(4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1)$.
To calcuate $\vert tr\rho(g) \vert $, by Frobenius Formula,
$$\chi_{\lambda}(g)=\left[\Delta(x)\cdot\prod_jP_j(x)^{i_j}\right]_{(l_1,\ldots,l_k)}.$$
Since $g$ is a transposition, as in the book "Representation Theory A
First Course", we define a sequence
$(i_1,\cdots,i_{20})=(18,2,0,\cdots,0).$ It means $g$ consists $18$
$1-$cycles and $1$ $2-$cycles.
For the partition $\lambda=(8,6,4,2)$, we define $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. Then
$$\Delta(x)\cdot\prod_jP_j(x)^{i_j}=\left(\prod_{1\le i<j\le
4}(x_i-x_j)\right)(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^{18}(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)^{2}.$$
Here I use Python program to compute the coefficient of
$x_1^{11}x_2^8x_3^5x_4^2$ in $\Delta(x)\cdot\prod_jP_j(x)^{i_j}$, it is zero.
So $\chi_{(8,6,4,2)}(g)=0$.
For the partition $(4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,)$, defnie $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_8$.
Then $$\Delta(x)\cdot\prod_jP_j(x)^{i_j}=\left(\prod_{1\le i<j\le
8}(x_i-x_j)\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^8 x_i\right)^{18}\left(\sum_{i=1}x_i^2\right)^{2}.$$

I need to compute the coefficient of $x_1^{11}x_2^{10}x_3^8x_4^7x_5^5x_6^4x_7^2x_8^1$.
I use Python for this, but Python will spend too much time.
Thus I think it maybe not a good method to solve this problem.
So I want to know if there exists another good method to solve this problem.
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

It's called the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule.

@DavidA.Craven  Thank you!  In the book "Representation Theory A First Course", the author also call it Frobenius  Formula.  But now I know that's what it's called.

@fusheng David meant a different (recursive) formula. Btw, where is the exercise from?
